# Why when I'm running fast lane snapshots do I get `** TEST FAILED **`?

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

When running the lane `'snapshots'` (documented [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/screenshots/)) with [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools),
I get

> ✗ testScreenshots, com... crashed in +[ADBApplicationOnlyFunctionality isRunningOnBackground]
>   ✗ testScreenshots, failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "Activity cannot be used after its scope has completed."

When I run the UITests/screenshots code I have directly from Xcode, it works..it's when I try to run from Fastlane that I have the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to disable the Main Thread Checker on my *UITests.framework scheme* in addition to doing so in my UITests scheme. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable the Main Thread Checker on the UITest scheme and also disable concurrent simulators in fastlane.

In the Snapfile, add this line:
`concurrent_simulators(false)`